# Sort Un-ordered XML using Java

Tags: java, xml

I want to sort un-ordered XML files so that two files can be comparable.
XML file should be sorted based on first outermost tag and then inner tags. I want some generic code.
For Example:

My XML file is :

```
<xn:rootElement>
    <subs:Parent id="2">
        <subs:Child1 id="2">
            <attributes>
                <attribute1></attribute1>
                <attribute2></attribute2>
            <attributes>
        </subs:Child1>

    </subs:Parent>
    <subs:Parent id="2">
        <subs:Child1 id="1">
            <attributes>
                <attribute1></attribute1>
                <attribute2></attribute2>
            <attributes>
        </subs:Child1>
    </subs:Parent>
</xn:rootElement>
```

I want the following result, as parent id is same it is sorted on base of child element.

```
<xn:rootElement>
    <subs:Parent id="2">
        <subs:Child1 id="1">
            <attributes>
                <attribute1></attribute1>
                <attribute2></attribute2>
            <attributes>
        </subs:Child1>

    </subs:Parent>
    <subs:Parent id="2">
        <subs:Child1 id="2">
            <attributes>
                <attribute1></attribute1>
                <attribute2></attribute2>
            <attributes>
        </subs:Child1>
    </subs:Parent>
</xn:rootElement>
```

Need to check every possibility , if parenet id is same then sort on base of child id.

Note: Size of XMLs is very Large.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I tried with XSLT but in that case i need to specify the tag with which i want to sort in style-sheet. I tried with SAXBuilder but i am not satisfied because    it is not even generic code.  I want some generic code.

Comment: Convert your XML to Java Objects using [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) or any other method you find it suitable, override [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and compare Objects. Comparing XMLs as a String is not a good approach.

Comment: how large is your xml. You said that you tried using xslt. did xslt transformation succeeded without OutOfMemory error.

Comment: Zaid Malhis , I just write example to show the what i want, my problem is I don't know the structure of XML, Actually I want to compare 2 un-ordered XMLS, for that i was thinking to first do sort and then i will use any tool for comparison. Give em some other suggestion..

Comment: Santhosh Kumar Tekuri : yes my xml file size is 260 MB approx for now, It can be large than 260 MB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have code ready to share. but Pseudocode is:

1. Try creating objects with Parent and having list of childs.
2. Sort the list of parents and its respective childs.
3. Create a XML again.